# How to tell windows 10 not to play a notification sound when the next song starts?

Tags: windows, windows-10, vlc-media-player

How to tell windows 10 not to play a notification sound when the next song starts e.g. in VLC Media Player?

It is ofc very annoying and dumb.

How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Settings App, click on System, Click on Notifications & actions, scroll down to 'Show notifications from these apps' and flip the switch for VLC to off.

It seems to get set back for some folks so what for that.

Comment: I have to revert my votes and comment. It still does not work, there is no VLC Media player appearing in the list.
EDIT: After closing and reopening the settings app, VLC Media player appeared.